# Laravel 5 - How can I pass html data to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**EDIT1**
It was my mistake, just using `{!! $message!!}` works

I'm trying to return those `<i></i>` tags to view, how can I render it in blade?

I tried this `{{ $message }}` and this `{!! $message !!}`

**Controller**

```
    $model_filial = new Filial();
    $alerts = [];
    if (!$model_filial->hasEmail($request->codigoempresa, $user->codigofilial)) {
        $filial = $model_filial->getFilial($request->codigoempresa, $user->codigofilial);
        $alerts[] = [
            'message' => "Não foi possivel enviar o e-mail pois a filial <i>".name_case($filial->nome)."</i> não possui um e-mail cadastrado",
            // --------------------------------------- HERE IS THE TAGS ^^^^^ ------------------------ ^^^^^^ --------------------------------
            'classes' => 'alert-danger'
        ];
    } else {
        $mail = new NewCotacao($request->codigoempresa, $codigocotacao);
        Mail::to('suporte9@siacomsistemas.com.br')->send($mail);
    }
```

**View**
Here I removed some code unnecessary for you guys, but I just show, alert, success, fails message, in alert message I need to render the `<i>` tag

```
<div id="content">
        @if(session()->has('alerts'))
            <div class="alert-wrapper">
                @if(session()->has('alerts'))
                    @foreach(session('alerts') as $alert)
                        <div class="alert {{ $alert['classes'] }}">
                       <!-- HERE IS WHERE I'M SHOWING THE MESSAGE -->
                            <p>{!! $alert['message'] !!}</p>
                            <span class="fonticon fonticon-close alert-close"></span>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
                <p class="alert alert-info alert-saving" style="display: none"><i class="fonticon fonticon-loading"></i>
                    Salvando...</p>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="alert-wrapper">
                <p class="alert alert-info alert-saving" style="display: none"><i class="fonticon fonticon-loading"></i>
                    Salvando...</p>
            </div>
        @endif
        @yield('content')
    </div>
```

**How it shows**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `strip_tags` to convert HTML tags.

```
<p>{!! strip_tags($alert['message']) !!}</p>
```

Or, you can also use `htmlspecialchars` function to print `<script>` or similar tags:

```
<p>{!! htmlspecialchars($alert['message']) !!}</p>
```

This will convert special entities to HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I know it was some function like that, but I just notice that it was a simple mistake in my code, I was changing this blade call `{{  }}` to `{!! !!}` in the wrong place kkk Thank you anyway it might be helpfull for another one

Comment: Ok! These things happen :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change blade call {{  }} to {!! !!}

Comment: This one worked! Thanks A lot!